# How to change the background color of another div when hover on another div?

Tags: css, html, hover, background-image

so, I am making an HTML on 'solar energy' as a school project. I am in seventh class in India.
I want that when one hovers on these divs with ids: #source,  #source_wr, and #arrow-right; the background color of the div with #source should change.

I am successful with hovering on #source itself, but  not on the other two.
here's the code I am using:

```
<div id="arrow-right"></div>
<div id="source_wr">Source</div>
<a href="http://www.wikipedia.org/" target="_blank">
<div id="source">
</div>
</a>
```

And here's the css:

```
#source_wr{
color: #56C8E3;
font-family: oswald, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: 200;
position:absolute;
top:210px;
right:300px;
}
#arrow-right{
width:0px;
height:0px;
border-bottom:25px solid transparent;
border-top:25px solid transparent;
border-left:25px solid #56C8E3;
position:absolute;
top:180px;
right:270px;
}
#source{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
right:0px;
height:240px;
width:264px;
background:url('wiki.png');
background-size:264px 240px;
}
#source:hover{
background:url('wikihover.png');
background-size:264px 240px;
}
#source_wr:hover + #source{
background:url('wikihover.png');
background-size:264px 240px;
}
```

but this isn't workingg !!! Please help, if i need to be more specific I will be... please don't say it cannot be achieved without Javascript ! And yeah, all the divs are directly inside the body ( but after a div which contains all of the main page and many more divs)

Thankyou in advance.

HERE'S THE LINK FOR THE ENTIRE HTML... DOWNLOAD EVERYTHING IN THE SAME FOLDER EXCEPT THE PSD FILES WHICH DON'T NEED TO BE DOWNLOADED. https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0BwFpYt0oAQbqT0xiUDNNRTVQOWs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please paste your entire html

Comment: FYI, [Is putting a div inside an anchor ever correct?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1827965/1577396)

Comment: @Mr_Green, in html5 just about anything can go in an anchor. [w3 html5 a](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a-changes)

Comment: Okay so this user1566160 asked for the entire HTML, so here it is:
https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0BwFpYt0oAQbqT0xiUDNNRTVQOWs/edit?usp=sharing

you will have to download everything in a same folder, but leave the .psd files because they are very very very heavy and don't include in the HTML in ANYWAY.

Comment: @slamborne yes you are right. here is the link http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a-changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [general-sibling-combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) `~`, it selects sibling any following sibling where as [`+`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinator) on selects the very next sibling.

```css
#source_wr:hover ~ a #source,#arrow-right:hover ~ a #source{
    background:url('wikihover.png');
    background-size:264px 240px;
}
```

Comment: sorry but i've tried it and for some reason it doesn't work :(.

Comment: @ThakurSakshamChauhan I didn't notice the `div` was in the `a`(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct), see update

Comment: Okay... so ... what do I do with the link part then if i have to remove the link... remember that I am in seventh class, from India and no specific teacher or else has taught me this.. I have learn EVERYTHING from the internet

Comment: Yeah! you were right! IT WORKED WHEN I DID IT expelling the anchor tag ! thankyou verymuch ! but the problem is that i want --> http://www.wikipedia.org/ to open in a new tab when one clicks on any of these...

Answer (score 0):

1. You didn't close your `<a>`
2. I'd suggest you change `<a>` to `<span>`

```
$('.source').on('click', function () {
    var url = $(this).find('span').attr('src');
    window.location(url);
});
$('.source').on('hover', function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#999'); //new color
}, function {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#666'); //original color
});
```

Comment: AM sorry @bobthyasian , but I want to minimize the use of javascript as much as I can !

Answer (score 0):

you can simply apply the effect with the following css

```
#source_wr:hover #source{*the effect you want on source*}
#arrow-right:hover #source {*The effect you want on source*}
#source:hover {*effect*}
```