# Change Background-Color of Child Div When Parent Div is Hovered

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, hover

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15060776/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-another-div-when-hover-on-another-div), but I'm not sure if the answer applies.

I'm trying to make it so that when you hover over any portion of this parent div:

[image]

The top div within it changes background-color:

[image]

I have:

```js
/*
Maybe something like this?

var oldBackground;
var parentNode = document.getElementByClassName('item');
var childNodes = document.getElementsByClassName('child');

parentNode.onmouseenter = e => {
    var c = e.target.childNodes[0]
    c && ((oldBackground = c.style.background) &c.style.background="blue")
};

parentNode.onmouseout = e => {
    var c = e.target.childNodes[0]
    c && oldBackground && (c.style.background=oldBackground)
};
*/
```

```css
.dashboard {
    display: flex;
}

.dashboard .item {
    border-radius: .25rem;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 20%;
}

.dashboard .item:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
}

.dashboard-item-top {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;

    /*this background color should change to #F2F3F3 when 
    .item div is hovered*/
}

.info-block-item {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard">
<div class="item">
    <div class="dashboard-item-top">
      Classes
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard-item-bottom">
      <span class="info-block-item">0</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure where to begin. Is it better to try this with JavaScript / jQuery or CSS?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/h1oas3tz/7/)

---

**EDIT**: Updated, working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/h1oas3tz/14/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add additional hover behavior in CSS to a child element like so:

```
/*on hovering the .item class, manipulate the child with the class .dashboard-item-top*/
.dashboard .item:hover > .dashboard-item-top {
    background: #CECECE;
    /*any other styles*/
}
```

```css
.dashboard {
    display: flex;
}

.dashboard .item {
    border-radius: .25rem;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    background: white;
    text-align: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 20%;
}

.dashboard .item:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
}

.dashboard .item:hover > .dashboard-item-top {
    background: #CECECE;
}

.dashboard-item-top {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;

    /*this background color should change to #F2F3F3 when 
    .item div is hovered*/
}

.info-block-item {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="dashboard-item-top">
      Classes
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard-item-bottom">
      <span class="info-block-item">0</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, and the key for my specific solution is to change the styles of the `border-color` of the parent div on hover as well: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HappyHands31/h1oas3tz/14/)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do essentially is change the color of the first child node, when the parent node is hovered over. I also assume you want to change it back when the hover leaves. So you need to add a mouseenter and mouseout event, changing `e.target.childNodes[0].style.background`
So, psuedo code

```
var oldBackground;
parentNode.onmouseenter = e => {
    var c = e.target.childNodes[0]
    c && ((oldBackground = c.style.background) &c.style.background="blue")
};

parentNode.onmouseout = e => {
    var c = e.target.childNodes[0]
    c && oldBackground && (c.style.background=oldBackground)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The below example might help in achieving what you want through CSS alone.

```css
#parent {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#parent:hover .parent-highlight {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div>hover over me</div>
    <div>hover over me</div>
    <div>hover over me</div>
    <div class="parent-highlight">I get highlighted</div>
</div>
```